# Correct way to design "me" endpoints

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I have a REST API to get current authenticated user's notifications and the user can be determined through Auth token. How should I define the endpoint?

```php
1. '/users/{user}/notifications' /* however in code I don't use the param {user}, but something like token->user */

2. '/notifications'
```

Answer (score -1):

Both are valid designs, and both styles are used by many people. I don't think there's a correct way here, there's just trade-offs.

Comment: trade-offs such as?

Comment: Lets use some critical thinking. What do you think the trade-offs might be? Especially in your situation. That might be a better way to discuss this.

Comment: First option shows the relationships clearly, that the api work on a user's notifications, but the api function itself already can determine the user without the param. Second option seems to indicate that the api is working on notifications instead of user's notifications.

Comment: @Soul'stearGo I think both of those are fair. Another difference I see is that if in the future you want user A to access user B's notifications, it's not possible if there's only 1 endpoint.